# Provide JSON Schema for a JSON file like settings JSON in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When editing settings JSON file, Visual Studio Code suggests property names. I am assuming it's using a JSON Schema internally.

It's a very nice feature and can be useful for editing other JSON files that have a JSON Schema. I can't find an option for adding schema to a JSON file. If it's an internal feature, where it is located in the source code and can we build an extension that surfaces the feature so we can provide JSON Schema for editing a JSON? Using `$schema` property doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out it's possible to provide those JSON Schemas. In `settings.json` there are a couple of examples for Bower and `package.json`

They are under `"json.schemas"`.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do it this way:

In your .json file, just after the first opening curly bracket, add `$schema` property that is the path to the schema file:

```
{
    "$schema": "../node_modules/sp-build-tasks/schema/v1/sppp.json",
     startTypinghere...
}
```

[More info](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-settings)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set the schema for a JSON file that should be using VSCode's settings schema, you can find your editor's current schema at `vscode://schemas/settings/user`.

To set that as the active schema for a JSON file, you could add this to the file:

```json
"$schema": "vscode://schemas/settings/user",
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to enable IntelliSense (and effectively, proper validation) for your JSON files:

1. #### `$schema` property in the file itself.

   Using `$schema` property in your JSON [does work in recent VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/json#_mapping-in-the-json), however the culprit here is that you'll need to have `$schema` as an allowed property in the very same schema you're referencing, otherwise it won't be valid.

   Although this might feel like a little self-recursive bloat, it has the advantage that any users of that JSON will get a reference to the schema no matter what editor they are using.

   Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/json#_mapping-in-the-json
2. #### Referencing schema in `settings.json`:

   ```json
   "json.schemas": [
     {
       "fileMatch": [
         "/*.foo.json"
       ],
       "url": "./myschema.json"
     }
   ]
   ```

   Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/json#_mapping-to-a-schema-in-the-workspace
3. #### Putting the schema directly into `settings.json`:

   ```json
   "json.schemas": [
     {
       "fileMatch": [
         "/.myconfig"
       ],
       "schema": {
         "type": "object",
         "properties": {
           "name" : {
             "type": "string",
             "description": "The name of the entry"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   ]
   ```

   https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/json#_mapping-to-a-schema-in-the-workspace