# How can I type a JSON file with TypeScript for VSCode?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, visual-studio-code, typescript-types

In a Node/TypeScript project if I'm editing the `tsconfig.json` or `package.json` file using VSCode then I get some helpful intellisense provided by the editor that it gets from TypeScript. So somewhere, I'm guessing, an association has been made between a `.d.ts` definition file and each of those files to provide this help.

My use case is that I have a number of `.json` files in a project that I have to maintain. These files are used by external tools so they can't be `.js` or `.ts` files. To make editing of these files less error prone I'd like to be able to write an associated `.d.ts` file and somehow tell the editor that this is the definition file for that `.json` file and then get all the editor help from that.

How do I do that?

Or, where are the `tsconfig.json` or `package.json` definition files and how does VSCode associate them?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-and-settings

Comment: @Phix copy/pasta the relevant parts of that page as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VSCode can utilize JSON schemas via the `$schema` key in the JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/coffeelint",
  "line_endings": "unix"
}
```

> Note that this syntax is VS Code-specific and not part of the JSON Schema specification. Adding the $schema key changes the JSON itself, which systems consuming the JSON might not expect, for example, schema validation might fail.

You can also define the structure in the settings:

```
"json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/.myconfig"
        ],
        "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name" : {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The name of the entry"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

[VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-and-settings)

Comment: `$schema` is not needed in JSON if the schema is defined via settings. Just to clarify for anyone who might be reading this answer for the first time. May be worth adding that the second approach replaces the first one.

Comment: Might be worth noting that you can also reference an external file in `settings.json`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77254593/1246547