# Where is the json schema of vscode settings.json

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

I know VSCode support json schema. So where is the json schema file of settings.json it self? I looked the https://www.schemastore.org/json/ and could not find it.

Comment: Why do you assume there is one? VSCode seems to have a more complex type based declaration for its own settings. JSON Schema on its own is probably to simple and not flexible enough https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/2ae55bc71641241d99cd1c79849c9823426790f2/src/vs/workbench/services/preferences/common/preferences.ts

Comment: If you want a definitive answer, you should probably log an issue on the repo.

Comment: When I try to open an issue on vscode repo, if it is a question, it says " Question
Please ask and answer questions here." and redirect to this site with [visual-studio-code] tag.

Comment: Wow, that's a little rude. Not all questions (and I would argue this for example) are suitable (considered "on topic") for Stackoverflow. I'm going to take a look at meta and see if I can clear this up.

Comment: HEre are some other possible channels: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Feedback-Channels#gitter-chat-room

Comment: I asked at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/507

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds not a duplicate. if anything, [that one](/q/34192948) is probably a duplicate of something else like [this](/q/30056721), though it has a particular angle/motivation/premise (the assumption that VS Code settings.json suggestions are based on a schema (I don't know whether this is true, since settings.json has extra features, such as the [preferences widget](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/preferences/browser/preferencesWidgets.ts))) that I might choose not to close that (/q/34192948) either.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode builds the schema dynamically, including information from extentions, so there is no file, per se.  However, if you add

```
{
   "$schema": "vscode://schemas/settings/user"
}
```

to a json file in VSCode, you will get code-completion, etc.

I originally found this in the answer from [@DudeOfAwesome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/985615/dudeofawesome) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77191395/)

Comment: Are you saying that this is a duplicate question of that one?

Comment: @Yunnosch read my comment on the question.

Comment: @starball Actually I am less interested in whether it actually is a duplicate than in whether the answers author thinks so.

Comment: Hi Timothy, welcome to Stack Overflow. Typically when you make an answer whose contents are entirely, 100% from someone else's answer, you're encouraged to mark the post as a 'community wiki' (and, when quoting verbatim, to use block quote formatting [e.g. `>`] for the quoted content) by clicking the checkbox to the bottom right of the input field when editing/writing the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of there being a schema file (some static piece of JSON schema text) for VS Code settings. If you're writing a JSON file *using* VS Code, you can add a top-level JSON member `"$schema": "vscode://schemas/settings/user",` (see also the `json.schemas` setting) to make VS Code use that schema for that file. That JSON schema is generated at runtime. See [`registerConfigurationSchemas` in src/vs/workbench/services/configuration/browser/configurationService.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/0608109a61142a7941206dfded0d462233036f5f/src/vs/workbench/services/configuration/browser/configurationService.ts#L1166).

Configuration points (settings) are registered/provided to VS Code in different ways. Some builtin ones are registered directly via code (Ex. see [src/vs/editor/common/config/editorOptions.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/common/config/editorOptions.ts)), and extension settings are registered [via the extension manifest](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration). Still, I'm not sure why VS Code doesn't publish a schema file for its builtin settings and set `additionalProperties` to `true` and provide some way to generate schema files for individual extensions (and then you could combine them). Maybe there just aren't enough people asking for it.